# How to make an alias to a part of a block device

Tags: linux, partitioning, alias

Is it possible to make a part of a block device to be seen as a separate block device (in a similar way block 'devices' are created for partitions)? Unfortunately, I can't mount it through loop device due to poor performance. Also, I can't add a partition table to the disk. Hardcoding necessary information into the kernel is a possible option if someone shows where to put what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `addpart` (from *util-linux*) to tell the kernel about partitions on a device.

```
SYNOPSIS
   addpart device partition start length

DESCRIPTION
   addpart is a program that informs the Linux kernel of new par‐
   tition.

   This command doesn't manipulate partitions on hard drive.
```