# Mount specific subset of block device or file as FS without a MBR/GPT

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, mbr

How can I mount a specific block range from a block device (or byte range from a file), or at least expose it as a loop device without loading the full MBR/GPT ?

I have a few use relevant use cases :

- Given a hard drive with a broken MBR/GPT, I want to mount a partition whose start/end sectors are known (as well as block size of course), but `dd`'ing it first isn't an option, due to partition size for example
- I have a backup image of a full disk (with partition table) in a file, i want to mount a specific partition from it without exposing all partitions as devices
- I want to do some ill-advised steganography by hiding a FS in a block device or file with start/end offsets to make it less obvious (I know it's not a good option due to entropy and access mappings, that's not the point here)

Last use case is more of a hack inspired by first and second use cases, which are actual problems I encountered.

I found a few related questions, like those :

- [How to map only a part (byte- or block-based) of a device file or regular file to a loop device?](https://superuser.com/questions/830467/how-to-map-only-a-part-byte-or-block-based-of-a-device-file-or-regular-file-t)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520459/linux-hard-disk-direct-access-without-any-fs-from-c-program

But the (valid) answers to these questions are often to `dd` partition or recreate MBR which is not an option here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a comment under [this already linked question](https://superuser.com/q/830467/432690):

> I found an answer which is using `losetup` with `-o` and `--sizelimit` options.

Also modern `mount` can do this. About loop devices in [`man mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> This type of mount knows about four options, namely `loop`, `offset`, `sizelimit` and `encryption`, that are really options to `losetup`.

So the syntax is like:

```
mount -o offset=OFFSET,other,options,here /image/file /mnt/foo
```

where `OFFSET` is in bytes. One usually knows the offset in 512-byte sectors. If starting sector is e.g. `2048` then this is useful:

```
mount -o offset=$((512*2048)),other,options,here /image/file /mnt/foo
```

In practice you hardly ever need `sizelimit` with `mount` because the filesystem you mount knows its own size.

Comment: thanks to your answer, another related question popped up with another option : https://superuser.com/questions/571836/how-to-make-an-alias-to-a-part-of-a-block-device